# Looking for VPCEA36FX driver's

Tags: drivers

I was trying to find Sony VPCEA36FX drivers for windows 7 32 bits, but without any success. At Sony's official website they only provide 64 bits option. 
What could I do ?
thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is targeted at _programming_ questions. This question is more suited for Super User.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://www.userdrivers.com/. It contains sony notebook drivers. Or a google search with "site:userdrivers.com".